# How to grant specific table ownership to specific user?

Tags: sql-server

I am intend to execute DBCC which is change seed identity on the sqlserver

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[dbo].[AUTO_CAMPAIGNTRX]', RESEED, 266)
```

Now when i execute this, i get this

```
User 'wlDBusr' does not have permission to run DBCC CHECKIDENT for object 'AUTO_CAMPAIGNTRX'.
```

But i cannot grant this user have db ownership because it involved many tables, i want to grant him the ownership to that particular table only.

What i have tried,

Right click the table and specific the user and grant him all access, not work.
[image]

Comment: The question should be asked in dba.stackexchange.com instead.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use exec proc

```
CREATE PROC dbo.chk
WITH EXECUTE AS OWNER
AS
DBCC CHECKIDENT ('[dbo].[a]', RESEED, 266)
GO
```